# how to hook gorminstance api in grail 3.x

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

how to hook custom gorminstance api in grail 3.x, gorm 6.x

below link is not working.

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/hooking-into-the-instance-methods-of-the-gorm-api/

gorm decorator groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.test.domain.UserInbox.currentGormInstanceApi() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the api?  Knowing that will help define what the best solution is.

Comment: @jeff
we want to set deepvalidate:false globally in our application..want to disable cacadeValidator,

Comment: Rahul, you should post a separate question and ask how to do that in particular.  Your question here implies a solution that is probably not the one you want.